# How to print an Excel sheet in a multi-column layout?

Tags: microsoft-excel

In my excel sheet I have three columns A, B, C that are very thin, but have a lot of lines (>500). Now if I print this out, I get 10 pages that are almost empty. Only at the left border of each page I see this three columns.

What I want to do, is to print that whole sheet in a multicolumn layout. 2 or 3 columns per page would be enough. Currently, I'm doing it by copying the values out of Excel, inserting it into a Word document and then use the multi-column layout function of Word. Isn't there a way to achieve that directly in Excel?

To clarify my problem:
Currently my pages look like that

```
A B C
A B C
A B C
A B C
. . .
```

But what I want is this:

```
A B C     A B C     A B C
A B C     A B C     A B C
A B C     A B C     A B C
. . .     . . .     . . .
```

Answer (score 11):

I don't think Excel can do that.  A possible work-around is to use Microsoft Word and snake the columns around: [How to snake columns to use fewer pages](http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/snakecol.htm)

> Using MS Word to Snake Columns   (#msword)
>
> This is probably the easiest to use for a one time usage, since I've not put in a dialog into my Excel macro described later.
>
> 1. Select and copy columns from Excel spreadsheet.
> 2. Paste into Word, this takes a few moments
> 3. Select the rows to be repeated at top in the table, then indicate this in Word with
>    Table --> Rows to repeated
> 4. Select entire table using anchor, or selecting cell(s) in the table and then
>    Table --> Select --> Table
> 5. Indicate number of rows using the columns button, or
>    Format --> Columns if you want more control over placement

This example works well.  The post offers other possibilities, too.

Answer (score 6):

If you have a source table called "datatable", put this formula on an extra sheet into every cell (where the printed data should appear):

```
=OFFSET(datatable!$A$2;(ROW()-2)+((COLUMN()-1-MOD(COLUMN()-1;3))/3*4);MOD(COLUMN()-1;3))
```

(*the above is translated from german into english. The tested german formula is:*  `=BEREICH.VERSCHIEBEN(datatable!$A$2;(ZEILE()-2)+((SPALTE()-1-REST(SPALTE()-1;3))/3*4);REST(SPALTE()-1;3))`)

## expected result:

This will transform the content of the sheet "datatable":

```
A1 B1 C1
A2 B2 C2
A3 B3 C3
A4 B4 C4
A5 B5 C5
A6 B6 C6
...
```

into:

```
A1 B1 C1    A5 B5 C5    ...
A2 B2 C2    A6 B6 C6    ...
A3 B3 C3    ...
A4 B4 C4    ...
```

## Explanation:

### Basics:

e.g. `OFFSET( datatable!$A$2; 3; 4 )` references the cell relative to `$A$2`, 3 rows down, 4 columns to the right.

`ROW()` and `COLUMN()` are numbers, representing the position of the current cell in the current sheet (e.g. `$A$1` = column 1/row 1, `$C$2` = column 3/row 2).

The `(-1)` everywhere are necessary because we are using offsets, and the first row and column is 1, but we want the first referenced cell to be `$A$2`, not `$A$2` plus offset 1.

The `(ROW()-2)` is for a headline in the output-/print-table (It shold be -1 if you don't have a headline).
`$A$2` is for a headline in the source "datatable". Without headline it should be referenced with `$A$1` (instead of `$A$2`).

### Details:

The 3rd parameter `OFFSET(...;...;MOD(COLUMN()-1;3))` is the **column offset**, it will always reference one of the first 3 columns of the source "datatable".
That is `$A$2` plus column offset 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, ...

In the 2nd parameter `OFFSET(...; (ROW()-2) + ((COLUMN()-1-MOD(COLUMN()-1;3))/3*4) ;...)` selects the **row offset**.
Basically the math here is y + x * 4.

4 is the number of rows you want to display.
3 is the number of colums in the source "datatable".

The x is made of the column and modulo 3.
`COLUMN()-1` is 0, 1, 2, 3, ... and so on.
`MOD(COLUMN()-1;3)` will be 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, ...

`COLUMN()-1-MOD(COLUMN()-1;3)` will be 0, 3, 6, 9, ... and so on, where the value is changing only every 3rd column.
Division by 3 will result in 0, 1, 2, 3, ...
Multiplication with 4 will result in 0, 4, 8, 12, ...

(For explaination about *Modulo*, see also `MOD()` in the excel help, or [modulo operation in wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation))

*(Thanks to Jake Kacher, for the basic idea)*

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple formula:

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,(ROW()-2)*5+COLUMN(),0)
```

to let the data flow horizontally in 5 columns.
Then you can select the page size, print the first row on each page, etc.
Simple, neat, no VBA needed.

Comment: Probably useful for an Excel Guru -- but I have no idea where I would put this or how to use it.

Comment: Doesn't exactly do what was requested, but is interesting none the less.If column A had a long series of numbers, then if you copied this formula to say C,D,E,F,G and dragged it down a sufficient number of rows, you would get 5 shorter columns of data.  The data flows across the five columns, while I expect you wanted the data to flow down each column and snake across.  Still, very interesting compact formula.

Answer (score 2):

Paste in word

Select entire table

Click LAYOUT

Click COLUMNS

Select the number of columns you desire

Comment: That answer has already been given

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: For those who use LibreOffice: click from the menu Format (instead of Layout) and then Columns. I had 8000 rows. Pasting it into Writer (Word) in one piece took too much memory. It worked for me to paste the table in pieces of 1000 rows, adjusting the table and font and only then moving on to the instructions in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I found was to create a new worksheet and simply recreate the table manually separating into separate columns.

e.g.
A1 `=Sheet1!A1`

B1 `=Sheet1!B1`

C1 `=Sheet1!C1`

D1 blank (for a divider column)

then
E1 `=Sheet1!E51`

F1 `=Sheet1!B51`

G1 `=Sheet1!C51`

And copy this down over 50 rows. This then turns a single column 100 row table into a 2 column 50 row table. Adjust to suit your needs.

Of course this is manual, and depends upon the row count remaining the same. It wouldn't be difficult to dynamically calculate the number of rows required from the number of rows in the original table and the number of columns you want. The only issue is if the original table expands beyond what will fit on a single page when separated into columns on the new sheet.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Adobe Indesign you can place excel file in it and make this layout with ease.