# How to Split one column in Excel into multiple columns of 55 rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office

I have a movie list with over 1500 entries (A1-A1500), all alphabetized (Thanks to Excel) and I would like to split that into multiple columns of 55 rows each on a separate sheet if possible.  So A1-A55 from Sheet1 would go to A1-A55 on Sheet2, and A56-A110 would go to B1-B55 on Sheet2, so on and so on.

Each cell is an individual movie name and I would just like them to go from one long column to multiple columns with 55 rows in each.

Comment: If you just want to have them all on one page for a dense printout, you're better off putting them into a word document and formatting it for multi-column ("newspaper"-like) display.

Comment: Similar to [How to print an Excel sheet in a multi-column layout?](https://superuser.com/q/414909/150988)

Answer (score 5):

If your data are on Sheet1, then fill in `Sheet2!A1` with

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet1!R" & (COLUMN()-1)*55+MOD(ROW()-1,55)+1 & "C1", FALSE)
```

Drag/fill this down to row 55 and out to column AB.  The first parameter of `INDIRECT` is a constructed string of the form `Sheet1!RnnnC1`, with `A1` evaluating to `Sheet1!R1C1`, `A55` –> `Sheet1!R55C1`, `B1`  –> `Sheet1!R56C1`, etc…  
`AB15` evaluates to `Sheet1!R1500C1`.

`INDIRECT(reference, FALSE)` retrieves the value from the cell referenced by *reference* using “R1C1” style, in which a row number and a column *number* are specified –– and of course these correspond to `A1:A1500` on Sheet1.

This will cause your data to *appear* in columns of 55 rows on Sheet2; it will still be linked to Sheet1.  To make a static copy, “Copy” the data (`A1:AB55` on Sheet2) and do “Paste Values”.  (To be safe, you might want to do this on Sheet3, then delete Sheet2.)

Answer (score 0):

If your data is comma (,) delimited then select the rows first then goto **`Data -> Text to column -> Click on Delimited radio button and click next -> Now choose Delimiters (if it is comma delimited the click on comma check box) and click next and finally Finish button`** and see the result.