# VBA - reformatting a 3 column into 9

Tags: microsoft-excel, printing, vba

My data looks something like this, very very long vertically.

```
#1, name1, number1
#2, name2, number2
#3, name3, number3
...
#2000, name2000, number2000
```

I want to reformat into 2 or 3 sets of column fitting into each printing page. Something like this

```
#1, name1, number1    #5    #9
#2, name2, number2    #6    #10
#3, name3, number3    #7    #11
#4, name4, number4    #8    #12
end of page 1
#13    #17   #21
#14    #18   #22
#15    #19   #23
#16    #20   #24
```

and so on.

I've never written VB codes before but I'm trying to adjust some existing code that I found to do this and I am running into an error. I counted the rows I need for each page and the number is 36.

```
Sub joeycol()
Dim count As Integer
count = 1

Dim desRow As Long
desRow = 1
Dim desColumn As Long
desColumn = 1

Dim srcRow As Long
Dim endRow As Long
endRow = 577

Dim srcColumn As Long

Dim wks As Worksheet
Set wks = Worksheets.Add

Dim x As Long

For srcRow = 1 To endRow
    If count = 4 Then
        count = 1
        desRow = desRow - 36
    End If

    For srcColumn = 1 To 3
        x = srcColumn * count
        Cells(desRow, x) = rng.Cells(srcRow, srcColumn)
    Next
    count = count + 1
    desRow = desRow + 1
Next
```

End Sub

This line right here keeps giving me error 1004 and the error message isn't giving me any clue :(

```
Cells(desRow, x) = rng.Cells(srcRow, srcColumn)
```

I've read some answers here with possibly better way to do this by copying range instead of looping like I did, but I have no time to study as I need to get this done ASAP and would appreciate if anyone can help me look into this.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print an Excel sheet in a multi-colum layout?](http://superuser.com/questions/414909/how-to-print-an-excel-sheet-in-a-multi-colum-layout)

Comment: Hi Andi. After some searching and trying, I'm now stuck on VBA code. I would appreciate if you can help please. Thank you!

Comment: at count `1` this line is setting itself equal to itself - `Cells(desRow, x) = rng.Cells(srcRow, srcColumn)`

Answer (score 0):

1004 errors are usually due to referencing an object (row, cell, column, range, etc.) that doesn't exist (at that point in time).

To start diagnosing, put a breakpoint on the line that's giving you the error, then step through checking the values (via Watches) for desRow, srcColumn, srcRow, rng, and count.  Check them at each iteration of the loop, and ensure they are referencing valid objects (that actually exist at that time).

Answer (score 0):

This will do that inserting page breaks along columns for pages that are only 36 rows long. This means it will have 72 3-column entries per page.

```
Sub test()
Dim wsOriginal As Worksheet
Set wsOriginal = ActiveSheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Set wsDest = Worksheets.Add

Dim lastrow As Integer
lastrow = wsOriginal.Cells(Rows.count, "a").End(xlUp).Row
Dim numSections As Integer
numSections = lastrow / 36
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer
k = 0

For i = 1 To lastrow
    If i > 36 * (k + 1) Then
        k = k + 1
    End If
    For j = 1 To 3
        wsDest.Cells((i - (36 * k)), j + (k * 4)) = wsOriginal.Cells(i, j)
    Next
Next

Dim lastCol As Integer
lastCol = wsDest.Cells(1, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Dim numPages As Integer
numPages = lastCol / 8

For Z = 1 To numPages
    wsDest.Columns(8 * Z).PageBreak = xlPageBreakManual

Next

End Sub
```